# static assertion failed with unordered map when using non-type template and empty lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, stdmap

The following class will trigger a static assert error within std::map due to differing `value_type`s of the allocator, despite the allocator being defaulted:

```cpp
template < bool store>
class MyClass {
  public:
   using hashmap_type = std::unordered_map< 
        int, 
        decltype([](){})
    >;

  private:
   std::map< int, hashmap_type > m_mapofmaps;
};
```

using it via `Myclass<false> v{};` triggers

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:191:21: error: static assertion failed: unordered container must have the same value_type as its allocator
  191 |       static_assert(is_same<typename _Alloc::value_type, _Value>{},
```

as can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xhdnaMrd8) (GCC 11.1):

But if the non-type template `store` is removed the compiler is suddenly having no issues anymore. The same holds for exchanging the lambda `[](){}` with another type, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xcxK3PYa6) and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qKr999MEM).

What is this odd interplay between the boolean non-type template, the lambda, and allocators?

Comment: It is not relevant that the template parameter is non-type. It always happens if the class is a template. I guess this is a GCC bug. Clang and MSVC compile it without complaint and the error message doesn't really seem to make sense.

Comment: Your `std::string` example on godbolt doesn't appear to have an error.  What are you actually trying to solve with your original formulation?  How would you ever use a unordered_map  of decltype([]{})?  I don't think you can create instances of `[]()` later, so what problem are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with how gcc substitutes default arguments to template parameters involving unevaluated lambda types.

A similar example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U = T>
struct assert_is_same {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, U>);
};

template<bool B>
struct X {
    assert_is_same<decltype([](){})> x;
};

int main() {
    X<false> a;
}
```

Without the `template<bool B>`, `decltype([](){})` is not a dependent expression, so is evaluated more eagerly (and you end up with something like `assert_is_same<_ZN1XILb0EEUlvE0_E, _ZN1XILb0EEUlvE0_E>`)

Inside the template, `[](){}`'s type is now dependent on `B`, so can't be replaced with a type immediately. It seems like gcc expands it to `assert_is_same<decltype([](){}), decltype([](){})>`, where those two lambdas are now different. (the default argument in your map example is `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>`, or `std::allocator<std::pair<const int, decltype([](){})>>`)

A workaround is to give the lambda something named it can hide behind:

```cpp
private:
    static constexpr auto lambda = [](){};
public:
    using hashmap_type = std::unordered_map< 
        int, 
        decltype(lambda)
    >;
    // allocator is now `std::pair<const int, decltype(lambda)>`, and
    // the two `decltype(lambda)`'s have the same type
```